# Dynamic variable in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have done the following code for an assignment:

```
DECLARE
   Ledger_rec   DDI.LEDGER_VIEW%ROWTYPE;

   PROCEDURE Var2Count(v_col IN NUMBER)
      IS
      BEGIN
         DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(TO_CHAR(NVL(v_col,0), '999,999'));
      END;
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('                  Total Head Count by Registration Date');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('REGDATE               101     102     103     104     105     106     107     108');
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------             -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----   -----');
   FOR Ledger_rec IN
      (
       SELECT * FROM
         (
          SELECT REGDATE, ADULTCNT, CHILDCNT, ROOMNUM
          FROM DDI.LEDGER_VIEW
         )
         PIVOT
         (
          SUM(CHILDCNT + ADULTCNT)
          FOR ROOMNUM IN ('101' AS r101,
                             '102' AS r102,
                             '103' AS r103,
                             '104' AS r104,
                             '105' AS r105,
                             '106' AS r106,
                             '107' AS r107,
                             '108' AS r108)
         )
       ORDER BY REGDATE
       )
    LOOP
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT(RPAD(Ledger_rec.REGDATE, 16));
       Var2Count(Ledger_rec.r101);
       Var2Count(Ledger_rec.r102);
       Var2Count(Ledger_rec.r103);
       Var2Count(Ledger_rec.r104);
       Var2Count(Ledger_rec.r105);
       Var2Count(Ledger_rec.r106);
       Var2Count(Ledger_rec.r107);
       Var2Count(Ledger_rec.r108);
       DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
    END LOOP;

EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No data found.');
END;
```

This is working except there is one thing I am missing from the assignment description:

> Use the dynamic variable, (CHILDCNT + ADULTCNT) HEADCNT, for the
>   aggregate SUM(HEADCNT)

So, I think my code should read `SUM(HEADCNT)`. How do I assign and use this dynamic variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define `HEADCNT` inside first block of parentheses and reuse it.

```
   SELECT * FROM
     (
      SELECT REGDATE, ADULTCNT, CHILDCNT, CHILDCNT + ADULTCNT HEADCNT, ROOMNUM
      FROM DDI.LEDGER_VIEW
     )
     PIVOT
     (
      SUM(HEADCNT)
      FOR ROOMNUM IN ('101' AS r101,
                         '102' AS r102,
                         '103' AS r103,
                         '104' AS r104,
                         '105' AS r105,
                         '106' AS r106,
                         '107' AS r107,
                         '108' AS r108)
     )
   ORDER BY REGDATE
```